# Connect to Microsoft SQL Server PHP on Mac

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

I have a Macbook with Yosemite. I download an app from apple store to try to run PHP code. I want to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server and this is the code:

```
$serverName = "astidbs";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"generale1", "UID"=>"xxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /private/var/folders/t5/zjgg2nv149x48bqqdhvnllcw0000gn/T/com.kukosk.PHP-Code-Tester/PHP_Code_Tester_tempfile.php on line 5
```

I can't understand if it was an app problem so I tried the code on an online tester but it doesn't work either. The error is the same but without the path. It seems that there isn't the lib for the specified call so I have searched on Google on how to install that but I wasn't able to solve the problem. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$myServer = "astidbs";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The problem is the same: Call to undefined function mssql_connect(). I have install freetds and have configure them but nothing work